# Sum of powers congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider the sum
$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n i^n,$$
and the sum mod $n$
$$M_n = S_N \text{ mod } n.$$
It is simple to prove that if $n$ is an odd prime then $M_n = 0$: if $n$ is  prime then the map $x \mapsto x^n$ is a field automorphism of $\mathbb F_n$, so then we get
$$M_n = \sum_{i=1}^n (i \text{ mod } n)^n = \sum_{x \in \mathbb F_n} x^n = \sum_{x \in \mathbb F_n} x = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \text{ mod } n.$$
Since $n$ is odd and prime, then $n > 2$ so $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} = 0 \pmod n$.

But looking at a plot of $M_n$, it seems like $M_n = 0$ for *every* odd $n$, and not only for *prime* odd $n$. How can I prove this statement? I don't see any way forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is odd, and $1\leq k < n$, then $k^n + (n-k)^n \equiv k^n + (-k)^n \equiv k^n - k^n \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$.

Pairing $k$ up with $n-k$ (since $n$ is odd, the two are never equal), we can see that $\sum_{i=1}^n i^n \equiv \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}} (i^n + (n-i)^n) \equiv 0\pmod{n}$.

Comment: Well, now that I know the answer, it's obvious! I heard my question first as a puzzle, so I suppose the answer should be something this simple. Thanks!